# Boolean variable in loop head as condition

Tags: python, loops

can someone help me with this project:

Guessing game to guess an integer.

There is a step called:

- Write the loop head containing the Boolean variable as a condition.

I don't understand this instruction.

My code:

```
question=input("Do you want to set the integer that shall be guessed? (Yes/No)")
if question == "yes":
    number=int(input("Integer that shall be guessed: "))
elif question == "no":
    number=58
else:
    print ("Please enter yes or no")   
guess=int(input("Enter a integer from 1 to 100! "))
guess_number=1
while guess != number:
    if guess < number:
        print("too small")
        guess=int(input("Enter a integer from 1 to 100! ")) 
        guess_number=guess_number+1
    elif guess > number:
        print("too large")
        guess=int(input("Enter a integer from 1 to 100! "))
        guess_number=guess_number+1
print("Correct!")
print(f'Number of attempts: {guess_number}')
```

I don't know how to implement the instruction to write the loop containing the boolean variable as a condition.

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not put code into pictures and link them in the question. Instead *please* insert the code vetbatim into the question itself. Thank you!

Comment: What do you/or your instructor mean by `Write the loop head containing the Boolean variable as a condition.`?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know what he means with that

Comment: maybe like `flag=True   while flag: if guess==number: flag=False elif .... : ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an infinite loop and break it on the correct input. The code can be something like

```
correct_num = 58
num_attempts = 1

while True:
    num = int(input("Enter an integer between 1 and 100! "))
    if (num < correct_num):
        print("too small")
        num_attempts += 1

    elif (num > correct_num):
        print("too large")
        num_attempts += 1

    else:
        print(f"Correct! Number of attempts: {num_attempts}")
        break
```